# Can't continue stellar-core sync. Stuck in Joining SCP

Tags: stellar-core

I'm in the middle process of stellar-core sync, but I need to restart my server for some reason so I stopped the stellar-core sync. Then when I continue the sync process I keep getting this message:

```
2018-09-20T20:06:35.026 GD53F [Process WARNING] process 2298 exited 22: curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/bucket/4d/cc/6b/bucket-4dcc6b478638ade092cf88e496060b7fde1ce0820b2d9d9b3e2565a3bf814543.xdr.gz -o buckets/tmp/repair-buckets-b05edc00d64260d6/bucket-4dcc6b478638ade092cf88e496060b7fde1ce0820b2d9d9b3e2565a3bf814543.xdr.gz.tmp
2018-09-20T20:06:35.026 GD53F [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 0 for get-remote-file bucket/4d/cc/6b/bucket-4dcc6b478638ade092cf88e496060b7fde1ce0820b2d9d9b3e2565a3bf814543.xdr.gz
2018-09-20T20:06:35.026 GD53F [Work WARNING] Scheduling retry #10/32 in 63 sec, for get-and-unzip-remote-file bucket/4d/cc/6b/bucket-4dcc6b478638ade092cf88e496060b7fde1ce0820b2d9d9b3e2565a3bf814543.xdr.gz
2018-09-20T20:07:00.575 GD53F [Process WARNING] process 2301 exited 22: curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/bucket/ea/76/07/bucket-ea760746301fdcda9c374bea5cae76c2238435b9d7f63c3af4111310881796b1.xdr.gz -o buckets/tmp/repair-buckets-b05edc00d64260d6/bucket-ea760746301fdcda9c374bea5cae76c2238435b9d7f63c3af4111310881796b1.xdr.gz.tmp
2018-09-20T20:07:00.575 GD53F [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 0 for get-remote-file bucket/ea/76/07/bucket-ea760746301fdcda9c374bea5cae76c2238435b9d7f63c3af4111310881796b1.xdr.gz
2018-09-20T20:07:00.575 GD53F [Work WARNING] Scheduling retry #11/32 in 1034 sec, for get-and-unzip-remote-file bucket/ea/76/07/bucket-ea760746301fdcda9c374bea5cae76c2238435b9d7f63c3af4111310881796b1.xdr.gz
```

This my stellar-core.cfg file:

```
NODE_SEED="mynodeseed"
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=stellar host=localhost user=myuser password=mypassword"

#FAILURE_SAFETY is minimum number of nodes that are allowed to fail before you no longer have quorum
FAILURE_SAFETY=1

# number of ledgers to synchronize (time in seconds divided by 5)
# NB: full validators should run with CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true instead
CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true
CATCHUP_RECENT=1024

LOG_FILE_PATH="/var/log/stellar/stellar-core.log"

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015"

# Populate NODE_NAMES, KNOW_PEERS, QUORUM and HISTORY sections with information
# on other validators
# for example https://github.com/stellar/docs/blob/master/validators.md
# or from https://dashboard.stellar.org/
NODE_NAMES=[
"GDIQKLQVOCD5UD6MUI5D5PTPVX7WTP5TAPP5OBMOLENBBD5KG434KYQ2  stronghold1",
"GAOO3LWBC4XF6VWRP5ESJ6IBHAISVJMSBTALHOQM2EZG7Q477UWA6L7U  eno",
"GCJCSMSPIWKKPR7WEPIQG63PDF7JGGEENRC33OKVBSPUDIRL6ZZ5M7OO  tempo.eu.com",
"GC5SXLNAM3C4NMGK2PXK4R34B5GNZ47FYQ24ZIBFDFOCU6D4KBN4POAE  satoshipay",
"GD7FVHL2KUTUYNOJFRUUDJPDRO2MAZJ5KP6EBCU6LKXHYGZDUFBNHXQI  umbrel",
"GCGB2S2KGYARPVIA37HYZXVRM2YZUEXA6S33ZU5BUDC6THSB62LZSTYH  sdf_watcher1",
"GCM6QMP3DLRPTAZW2UZPCPX2LF3SXWXKPMP3GKFZBDSF3QZGV2G5QSTK  sdf_watcher2",
"GABMKJM6I25XI4K7U6XWMULOUQIQ27BCTMLS6BYYSOWKTBUXVRJSXHYQ  sdf_watcher3",
]

KNOWN_PEERS=[
"core-live-a.stellar.org:11625",
"core-live-b.stellar.org:11625",
"core-live-c.stellar.org:11625",
"validator1.stellar.stronghold.co",
"stellar.256kw.com",
"stellar1.tempo.eu.com",
"stellar.satoshipay.io"
]

# full validators (with history archive)
[QUORUM_SET]
VALIDATORS=[
"$sdf_watcher1", "$sdf_watcher2", "$sdf_watcher3"
]

# other validators that you want to include
# for best result, use a number of validators
# that can be expressed as 3f+1 (4, 7, 10 ,...)
[QUORUM_SET.basic]
VALIDATORS=[
"$stronghold1", "$eno", "$tempo.eu.com", "$satoshipay"
]

# History archives

# Stellar.org history store
[HISTORY.sdf1]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.sdf2]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_002/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.sdf3]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/{0} -o {1}"
```

**"horizon_version": "0.14.0
"core_version": "stellar-core 10.0.0rc4**

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: You should probably upgrade stellar-core to [`10.0.0`](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/releases/tag/v10.0.0) (you can also upgrade horizon to `0.14.1` but it's not related to core sync).

Comment: Hello @BartekNowotarski thanks for your reply.
my stellar-core version is 10.0.0rc4 is it different from 10.0.0 ?

Comment: Yes, these are different versions (https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/compare/v10.0.0rc4...v10.0.0).